# How i can create a Slow mode command?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a command that enables slowmode in every channel in case of a raid. But it can only be used by a specific role. How do I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loop through every channel and set a rate limit per user on each one**

On [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/), you will find that [`Discord.TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) has a method called [`.setRateLimitPerUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setRateLimitPerUser). It takes an argument to represent the number of seconds to set as a rate limit per user.

Loop through the necessary channels in the guild and call this method on each one of them, with the desired number of seconds for slowmode.