# The command that im trying to use is not working. im not so familiar with making a discord bot but i understand it, but I can't solve this problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Can someone tell me why the command doesn't work? When i write the prefix and the command, it works but it says this message:

```
You did not specify a correct amount of time!
```

That's how it should, but if I write any other number next to it so i can set the slowmode, it just doesn't do anything. If someone can analyze the code and tell me the problem, it would be very appreciated. And yes, there is a token but I removed it so that it doesn't get leaked.

```js
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("ChatSlowMode is Online!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split();
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "slowmode") {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
      return message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command!");
    if (!args[0])
      return message.channel.send(
        "You did not specify a correct amount of time!"
      );
    if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("That is not a number!");
    if (args[0] > 21600)
      return message.channel.send(
        "Invalid Number! Number must be below 21600."
      );
    message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0]);
    message.channel.send(`Slowmode Set to **${args[0]}**`);
  }
});

client.login("");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot set slowmode outside of certain numbers. They're just like how you'd set it up in the channel settings of a server. This section looks like this:
[image]

Now, as you can see, you can only set it to `5s`, `10s`, `15s`, `30s`, `1m`, `2m`, `5m`, `10m`, `15m`, `30m`, `1h`, `2h`, `6h`. When you set it to an amount that isn't specified, then it will throw this error:

```
You did not specify a correct amount of time!
```

What you wan to do is, check for the number in the args, and check if it **is** a number. Try following the code below:

```js
// Disable this if you're already using the command below.
// This can cause `command` to be defined twice and return a constant value error.

// const commandFiles = fs
//     .readdirSync('./commands/')
//     .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
// for(const file of commandFiles){
//     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
//     client.commands.set(command.name, command);
// }

client.on('ready', () => {
 // `client.on()` should be better
 console.log('ChatSlowMode is Online!');
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
 // Check if message doesn't starts with `prefix` instead, or it will stop your code.
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const command = message.content
  .slice(prefix.length)
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')[0]
  .toLowerCase();

 const args = message.content
  .slice(prefix.length)
  .split(' ')
  .slice(1);

 if (command === 'slowmode') {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS'))
   return message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command!");

  // Checks if `args[0]` doesn't exist or isn't a number.
  if (!args[0])
   return message.channel.send('You did not specify a correct amount of time!');
  if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send('That is not a number!');

  // Check if `args[0]` is a correct amount of time to set slowmode
  // Array `validNumbers` are an array consistent of numbers of time you can set slowmode with.
  const validNumbers = [
   5,
   10,
   15,
   30,
   60,
   120,
   300,
   600,
   900,
   1800,
   3600,
   7200,
   21600,
  ];

  // Check if `args[0]` parsed into an interger is included in `validNumbers`
  if (!validNumbers.includes(parseInt(args[0])))
   return message.channel.send('Invalid Number! Number must be below 21600.');

  // Set the slowmode
  message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0]);

  // Send the reply
  message.channel.send(`Slowmode Set to **${args[0]}**`);
 }
});

client.login('');
```

See these references if you still don't understand:

- [Discord.js.org - Docs - Setting Rate Limit per User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setRateLimitPerUser)
- [How i can create a Slow mode command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008762/how-i-can-create-a-slow-mode-command)
- [How can I make my bot set a slowmode on a Discord channel, Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314278/how-can-i-make-my-bot-set-a-slowmode-on-a-discord-channel-discord-js)

Comment: So, for example, I can't set the slowmode to 35 minutes?

Comment: No, you can't, because discord doesn't allow that.

Comment: I added 14 in the validNumbers and I tried it, and it worked. idk how

Comment: That should't be possible, did you check if the slowmode is actually set to 14 seconds? It shouldn't be.

Comment: yes, and i have set it so i can be set to any number less than 21600

Comment: Okay, so apparently, after I asked my friends, the latest Discord API update allowed this, so the bot can set the time outside of these numbers, but not the users. I don't know if this was a bug and if it will be removed in the future or not, so I don't recommend it.